# How to perform a redirect based on the value entered in a Webform component?

Tags: rules, webforms

How to perform a redirect after a [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) submission, i.e. to different pages for different answers?

The scenario is like so:

- If user enters "`foo`" for some Webform component, then page must be redirected to `/foo`.
- If user enters "`anything else but foo`", then page must be redirected to `/bar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve by altering the Webform.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'YOURFORMID') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'ctm_redirect';
  }
}

function ctm_redirect(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (CONDITIONS) {
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'foo';
   }
   else{
     $form_state['redirect'] = 'bar';
   }
}
```

You can also check [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) module.

This module adds rules integration on webforms.

> Did you ever want to react on webform submission using rules but
>   couldn't find the proper event? Webform Rules makes it possible to
>   catch webform submissions by rules and do whatever you'd like to do
>   with it (meaning: do whatever rules let you do with it).

Comment: [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) is indeed part of a solution based on [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). However in that scenario the challenge is to get access to the value entered in the webform component. Refer to my answer for more details ...

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the previous answer, you can also get this to work with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module (cfr. the [rules](/questions/tagged/rules) tag in your question), as further explained below (and assuming this question is about D7) ...

At a minimum, make sure you have the [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) module enabled. Some details about it (from its project page):

> This module adds rules integration on webforms.
>
> Did you ever want to react on webform submission using rules but couldn't find the proper event?
>
> Webform Rules makes it possible to catch webform submissions by rules and do whatever you'd like to do with it (meaning: do whatever rules let you do with it).

However, you should also have a look at feature request "[Expose submission data to Rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2020149)". Here is a summary of it:

> Right now, submission data is not exposed to rules except by way of token replacement or custom php actions. This patch exposes submission data in a "first-class" way.

Issue status is "Needs work" ... not an "easy" issue.

## Time for a work around ...

The very same issue contains a [comment with a workaround](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules/issues/2020149#comment-12205966) (it's genious I think, because it's so simple), here is a relevant quote from it:

> You can initialize a rules string variable with the tokens. If you need integers or booleans you can subsequently convert it to whatever and then use it to load nodes or whatever.

A picture is worth more then 1000 words, checkout the [screenprint included in that comment](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/exposed_submission_workaround.png).

## ... and a demo

Consider this rule (in Rules export format):

```
{ "rules_redirect_based_on_a_component_value_of_a_submitted_webform" : {
    "LABEL" : "Redirect based on a component value of a submitted webform",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "rules_conditional", "webform_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "webform_rules_submit" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "form-id" ], "value" : "5" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "variable_add" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "text", "value" : "[data:contact_us_target-value-raw]" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "submitted_form_component_value" : "Submitted form component value" } }
        }
      },
      { "CONDITIONAL" : [
          {
            "IF" : { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "submitted-form-component-value" ], "value" : "foo" } },
            "DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "foo" } } ]
          },
          { "ELSE" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "bar" } } ] }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Some details about the above rule:

- Rules Event: After a webform has been submitted
- Rules Condition: Form-id has value "`5`" (change to whatever form-id to fit your case).
- Rules Actions:

  - Add a variable (this is the clue of it all ...), named `submitted_form_component_value` and with label "Submitted form component value", and with value `[data:contact_us_target-value-raw]` (the form component we want to use in subsequent Rules Actions).
  - Use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module to perform a data comparison. In this case it checks if it is `foo`. If so, then perform Rules Action "Page redirect to `foo`", otherwise perform Rules Action "Page redirect to `bar`".

PS: In this example I'm using the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module, though you could also rework the Rules Action to performing Rules Components (in which you add the appropriate Rules Conditions), so that you don't need this extra module. For more details on that, refer to the answer to "[What's the alternative to using the Conditional Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/245049/39516)".